# Spring Boot: How to add an Unconventional PropertySource

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties

### Our Property Manager

The system that we are designing uses an unconventional way to get property values, compared to Spring's pattern of using 'application.properties' files.  Without getting into too much detail, the property manager that we use uses a remote key value store to get properties for multiple datacenters.

The goal is we'd like to be able to use ***[@Value("${prop.from.propMan}")](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Value.html)***, which can usually be achieved by overriding the ***[PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html)***.  It's a very convenient way to get properties in Spring and it would be great if we could use this to get properties from our PropMan.

---

### Attempt #1:  Overriding PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer

Here's an example of how I've tried doing this:

```
@Bean
public PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {

    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer pspc = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();

    MutablePropertySources ps = env.getPropertySources();

    pspc.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(Boolean.TRUE);
    pspc.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);

    ps.addFirst(new PropManPropertySource("propMan", propMan()));

    pspc.setPropertySources(ps);

    return pspc;

}
```

---

### Attempt #2:  Add PropManPropertySource in the ApplicationContext

Another thing I have tried doing is add an ***[ApplicationContextInitializer](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContextInitializer.html)*** to add the new PropManPropertySource to the ***[PropertySources](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySources.html)*** when the application context is being initialized.  Here's a more complete example, showing the application class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application app = new Application();
        app.start(args);
    }


    private void start(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class)
                .initializers(new AppContextInitializer()).build().run(args);
    }

    /**
    *   We need to have an initializer for the ApplicationContext, or else there's no way to have the PropertySource
    *   added.  
    *   
    *   One problem I see here is the way the PropMan object is added is that it's not Autowired, so I'm calling the
    *   method directly propMan().  Ideally it would be autowired and would use simply propMan.  When autowiring in 
    *   this class there is an exception "PropertySource cannot be null".
    *
    *   One other thing I've tried was adding PropertyPlaceholderConfiguration, which adds the PropertySource.
    **/
    @Configuration
    public class AppContextInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {

        @Override
        public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext ac) {
            ConfigurableEnvironment env = ac.getEnvironment();
            MutablePropertySources propertySources = env.getPropertySources();
            PropManPropertySource propManPropertySource = new PropManPropertySource("propMan", propMan());
            propertySources.addLast(propManPropertySource);

            env.addActiveProfile("app");
        }
    }


    @Bean
    public PropMan propMan() {
        PropManImpl propMan = new PropManImpl();
        propMan.init();

        return propMan;
    }

}
```

Here's the ***PropManPropertySource***, which extends the ***[ProperySource](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/PropertySource.html)***.  This is where our PropMan's get method is called to retrieve the value from the key/value store.

```
public class PropManPropertySource extends PropertySource<PropMan> {

    PropMan propMan;

    public PropManPropertySource(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    public PropManPropertySource(String name, PropMan propMan) {
        super(name, propMan);
        this.propMan = propMan;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getProperty(String key) {
        return propMan.get(key);
    }

}
```

---

### Property Order and the Unexpected Behavior

While either does appear to override the PropertySource, it seems it wants to get all the properties that depend on the auto config from the PropMan as well.  For example, tries to check our PropMan for values like *spring.boot.enableautoconfiguration*.  Our PropMan makes an http request returns a 404 for each of these.  The return value is null, which would make me assume that it should look to the next PropertySource.  Ideally, it should see that it's not in PropMan and continue to check another PropertySource in PropertySources:

1. ***propMan***
2. commandLineArgs
3. servletConfigInitParams
4. servletContextInitParams
5. systemProperties
6. systemEnvironment
7. random
8. applicationConfigurationProperties
9. defaultProperties

---

Here's a snapshot of the log from the executable jar when I run it:

```
...

2017-02-18 14:31:49,214 INFO [main] c.h.c.LifecycleService [StandardLoggerFactory.java:49] [localhost]:5653 [dev] [3.5.5] Address[localhost]:5653 is STARTED
2017-02-18 14:31:49,265 INFO [main] c.g.a.s.a.m.PropManImpl [PropManImpl.java:271] get(String key=spring.profiles.active)
2017-02-18 14:31:49,270 INFO [main] c.h.p.InternalPartitionService [StandardLoggerFactory.java:49] [localhost]:5653 [dev] [3.5.5] Initializing cluster partition table first arrangement...
2017-02-18 14:31:49,302 INFO [main] c.g.a.s.a.m.PropManImpl [PropManImpl.java:291] URI: http://localhost:8500/v1/kv/com/myco/spring/profiles/active
2017-02-18 14:31:49,464 ERROR [main] c.g.a.s.a.m.PropManImpl [PropManImpl.java:298] Request to Consul recieved status code 404.
2017-02-18 14:31:49,467 INFO [main] c.g.a.s.c.Application [StartupInfoLogger.java:48] Starting Application on LOCALHOST with PID 8362
2017-02-18 14:31:49,467 INFO [main] c.g.a.s.c.Application [SpringApplication.java:641] The following profiles are active: app
2017-02-18 14:31:49,467 DEBUG [main] o.s.b.SpringApplication [SpringApplication.java:665] Loading source class com.myco.Application
2017-02-18 14:31:49,539 DEBUG [main] o.s.b.c.c.ConfigFileApplicationListener [DeferredLog.java:172] Loaded config file 'jar:file:myapp/build/libs/myapp-0.0.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/application.properties' (classpath:/application.properties)
2017-02-18 14:31:49,539 DEBUG [main] o.s.b.c.c.ConfigFileApplicationListener [DeferredLog.java:172] Skipped (empty) config file 'jar:file:myapp/build/libs/myapp-0.0.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/application.properties' (classpath:/application.properties) for profile default
2017-02-18 14:31:49,540 INFO [main] o.s.b.c.e.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext [AbstractApplicationContext.java:582] Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@1e9e725a: startup date [Sat Feb 18 14:31:49 EST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-02-18 14:31:49,543 DEBUG [main] o.s.b.c.e.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext [AbstractApplicationContext.java:616] Bean factory for org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@1e9e725a: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@6107227e: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerProcessor,org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerFactory,application]; root of factory hierarchy
2017-02-18 14:31:49,703 INFO [main] c.g.a.s.a.m.PropManImpl [PropManImpl.java:271] get(String key=spring.boot.enableautoconfiguration)
2017-02-18 14:31:49,704 INFO [main] c.g.a.s.a.m.PropManImpl [PropManImpl.java:291] URI: http://localhost:8500/v1/kv/com/myco/spring/boot/enableautoconfiguration
2017-02-18 14:31:49,795 ERROR [main] c.g.a.s.a.m.PropManImpl [PropManImpl.java:298] Request to Consul recieved status code 404.
2017-02-18 14:31:49,935 INFO [main] c.g.a.s.a.m.PropManImpl [PropManImpl.java:271] get(String key=spring.messages.basename)
2017-02-18 14:31:49,936 INFO [main] c.g.a.s.a.m.PropManImpl [PropManImpl.java:291] URI: http://localhost:8500/v1/kv/com/myco/spring/messages/basename
2017-02-18 14:31:50,045 ERROR [main] c.g.a.s.a.m.PropManImpl [PropManImpl.java:298] Request to Consul recieved status code 404.
2017-02-18 14:31:50,108 INFO [main] c.g.a.s.a.m.PropManImpl [PropManImpl.java:271] get(String key=server.error.whitelabel.enabled)
2017-02-18 14:31:50,109 INFO [main] c.g.a.s.a.m.PropManImpl [PropManImpl.java:291] URI: http://localhost:8500/v1/kv/com/myco/server/error/whitelabel/enabled
2017-02-18 14:31:50,203 ERROR [main] c.g.a.s.a.m.PropManImpl [PropManImpl.java:298] Request to Consul recieved status code 404.
2017-02-18 14:31:50,203 INFO [main] c.g.a.s.a.m.PropManImpl [PropManImpl.java:271] get(String key=server.error.whitelabel.ENABLED)
2017-02-18 14:31:50,204 INFO [main] c.g.a.s.a.m.PropManImpl [PropManImpl.java:291] URI: http://localhost:8500/v1/kv/com/myco/server/error/whitelabel/ENABLED
2017-02-18 14:31:50,306 ERROR [main] c.g.a.s.a.m.PropManImpl [PropManImpl.java:298] Request to Consul recieved status code 404.
2017-02-18 14:31:50,307 INFO [main] c.g.a.s.a.m.PropManImpl [PropManImpl.java:271] get(String key=server_error_whitelabel_enabled)
2017-02-18 14:31:50,309 INFO [main] c.g.a.s.a.m.PropManImpl [PropManImpl.java:291] URI: http://localhost:8500/v1/kv/com/myco/server_error_whitelabel_enabled
2017-02-18 14:31:50,404 ERROR [main] c.g.a.s.a.m.PropManImpl [PropManImpl.java:298] Request to Consul recieved status code 404.
2017-02-18 14:31:50,405 INFO [main] c.g.a.s.a.m.PropManImpl [PropManImpl.java:271] get(String key=server_error_whitelabel_ENABLED)
2017-02-18 14:31:50,406 INFO [main] c.g.a.s.a.m.PropManImpl [PropManImpl.java:291] URI: http://localhost:8500/v1/kv/com/myco/server_error_whitelabel_ENABLED
2017-02-18 14:31:50,498 ERROR [main] c.g.a.s.a.m.PropManImpl [PropManImpl.java:298] Request to Consul recieved status code 404.
2017-02-18 14:31:50,499 INFO [main] c.g.a.s.a.m.PropManImpl [PropManImpl.java:271] get(String key=serverErrorWhitelabel.enabled)
2017-02-18 14:31:50,500 INFO [main] c.g.a.s.a.m.PropManImpl [PropManImpl.java:291] URI: http://localhost:8500/v1/kv/com/myco/serverErrorWhitelabel/enabled
2017-02-18 14:31:50,612 ERROR [main] c.g.a.s.a.m.PropManImpl [PropManImpl.java:298] Request to Consul recieved status code 404.
2017-02-18 14:31:50,613 INFO [main] c.g.a.s.a.m.PropManImpl [PropManImpl.java:271] get(String key=serverErrorWhitelabel.ENABLED)
2017-02-18 14:31:50,614 INFO [main] c.g.a.s.a.m.PropManImpl [PropManImpl.java:291] URI: http://localhost:8500/v1/kv/com/myco/serverErrorWhitelabel/ENABLED

...  this goes on seemingly forever.
```

---

Has anyone been able to use an alternate property source?  How can I achive using PropMan as a PropertySource?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Andreas  The goal is we'd like to be able to use @Value("${prop.from.propMan}"), which can usually be achieved by overriding the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.  But you can see by the output I've posted that this isn't working correctly.  See 'unexpected behavior'.

Comment: I still don't see the problem. Yes all property sources will be consulted until the property is found. As yours is the first it will always be consulted and that is what you see. So again what isn't working for you? Looks to mee as if you are only bother by the logging.

Comment: Isn't your code working? You can override `containsProperty` if you only want to check a certain set of properties with your `PropMan` implementation.